# Should I store passwords using php serialize instead of using database?

Tags: php, ajax, passwords, storage

I'm editing web pages directly using ajax, and php with simple html dom. I dont see the point of using a database when I can do without. However, my hands go cold with fright when I think of storing admin password for the app on the webserver using serialize even though it is above htdocs, it is encrypted and I am using an anti brute force script.

I dont want to use a database just for one password but is it secure enough?

I look forward to your thoughts...

Comment: well, so long as you're okay with your password being stored in clear text on your server I suppose it's not an issue... Also, this question really isn't appropriate for this site. You're trying to solicit opinion.

Comment: This is the admin password? Why use serialize? I would create an md5 hash, store that as a var in the php file, and check passwords based on that

Comment: @BrianDriscoll He specifically stated "it is encrypted" ... and a clear text password in a database is no more secure than a clear text password in a text file.

Comment: Blimey, you lot were quick. I was canvassing opinion but on a technical matter, I figured it was alright. Looks like the general opinion is that there is no real difference as long as I encrypt and chmod it properly. I was under the misapprehension that databases these days had fancy security widgets!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file with the correct chmod permissions is just as secure as a database storage in this instance.

Think about it: the mysql database is actually stored in binary files on your server's filesystem. If a malicious user gains access to your server they have the same access to the binary database files as any other file, including your serialized and encrypted data in a text file.

As long as this text file isn't in a directory that's publicly accessible via the web server it's no less secure. Of course, if someone gets root access you're pretty much foobar'd either way.

What you should **never** do is store clear text passwords. `md5()` is (just) okay. [`sha1()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) has now emerged as a better option for encrypting this type of data.

Comment: Everybody has been very helpful but i guess ive got to choose one answer.

Answer (score 2):

Database doesn't let you have your password more secure than in file system, because in case your server gets hacked, your database password gets hacked too, which means that the admin password will be revealed in any case

Answer (score 1):

If this login is and will be for you only, it's quite easier to store your password in your code/ in a file. But you have to encrypt your password to prevent hackerkiddies from reading this file and login. Please don't forget right chmods on the file ;)

Comment: What if it was wasn't just one (i know i am changing the parameters of my question, but please bear with me) and users could choose their passwords? Is it still just a matter of encryption and benchmarking the speed against a db?

Comment: If there are multiple logins, you could do it with a textfile, but it's quite easier to manage those logins with a db. And in those small systems benchmarking is really small thing. A db is faster then you think. And sure, encription is also in a db very important

Answer (score 1):

As long as you aren't storing the plain-text password in the file, I don't see a problem with keeping a password hash in the actual php file.

Example using SHA1:

```
if(sha1($_POST['password']) == "8cb2237d0679ca88db6464eac60da96345513964") {
    //success
} else {
    //failure
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should store your "Hash" somewhere secure ( the key you're generating a password with) . it doesnt matter where you store that password if someone can get to the "hash / key", they can get to your passwords. the nice thing about a database is that it's most likely going to be easier to traverse your directory structure and find a file than it is to connect to your database, discover your table structure, then discover the values stored in a field in the database..

Comment: I thought it might be. I don't know the first thing about how people go about hacking (apart from sql injectio attacks). So that's a vote for going the database route then.

Comment: @Tom - there are really a lot of variables to consider in this situation, how many users, how high a profile is the site (would it be a target for a serious attack?) I would go the database route if you ever think you might be using a database in the app in the future. Moving data into a database from flat files sounds like more pain then setting up a database..